# PeerJS with hybrid android applications

Tags: android, ios, meteor, crosswalk, peerjs

I am using PeerJS in my Meteor project for audio calls between users. The functionality works find in browsers but when I test it in IOS or Android the call doesn't go through.

I came across [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/tutorials/webrtc.html) that supports WebRTC on Android and I can implement PeerJS with it.

My questions here are:

1) Does PeerJS require Crosswalk to function on Android?

2) If the answer to above question is yes, what should I use in order for PeerJS to function in IOS application?

Answer (score 0):

PeerJS is just some javascript code that opens a socket to the peerJS server, and sends some http requests to establish a connection pathway. It can work on any browser platform as long as the browser supports it. There are a couple of checks in the peerjs code which stops if it detects Safari, but you can comment that out, and it will go further. The roadblock finally is webrtc.

IOS support isn't there yet for webrtc, although Apple have announced that it is coming. No idea how long that will take.

Comment: I want the application to make the calls from the hybrid apps not the browsers if that makes different. From the WebRTC website, it says that IOS and Android platforms are supported. Doesn't that mean that it should work? I found tutorials of implementing crosswalk with peerjs for android hybrid apps. I want to know if I should learn crosswalk and use it in order for peerjs to work in android or peerjs doesn't require crosswalk?